# wtfroms validation doesn't seem to work after changing field data on serverside

Tags: flask, wtforms

I'm trying to validate form by ajax and wtforms, I have a form with one field like this:

```
name = StringField('Name :', description = "enter your name", validators=[InputRequired(message='please enter your name')])
```

And my serverside code is like this:

```
@app.route('/validation', methods=['get', 'post'])
def validation():
    data = request.get_json(force = True)
    myform = MyForm()
    for field in myform:
        field.data = data[field.name]
    myform.validate()
    return jsonify(myform.errors)
```

I send field data by json and then i set it to field, i checked it and its data exists in myform.data but after validating InputRequired error still exist in response.

Comment: It is a little bit unclear. Can you try to explain it a bit please :)

Comment: I get a dictionary of form's data from request and I want to fill the form fields on serverside and validate it, When i fill the fields by a for loop that I mentioned in my question, validate() method does not seem to notice changes, and It returns InputRequired error in my form errors!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: to validate form by ajax.

Comment: Validation can be done inside the form class. Not sure if validating in views.py is good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the form inside the form class itself.

```
class YouForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name :', description = "enter your name", validators=[InputRequired(message='please enter your name')])

    def validate(self):
        valid = True
        if not self.name.data:
            self.name.errors.append('* Either file or text is required')
            valid = False
        return valid
```

This way you can simply call validate method from view function in `views.py` file for validation.

Comment: What if I use other validators in my form? Your answer just work for InputRequired validators, There should be a better way.

Comment: You mean, you have other fields in your form? What exactly do you mean by "other validatiors"? Can you give example of that?

Answer (score 0):

It you are sending data through ajax and want server side validation just simple use `request.form`

```
@app.route('/validation', methods=['get', 'post'])
def validation():
    data = request.get_json(force = True)
    myform = MyForm(request.form)
    if myform.validate():
        #do something
        #return somthing
    else:
        return jsonify(myform.errors)
```